# failed error 1 code with intalling scipy and sckit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Everytime I try to install certain packages with `pip3`, such as `sklearn` or `scipy` I keep getting the error:

> Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-379iloop/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2bvcjei9-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-379iloop/scikit-learn

I tried using `anaconda3` for the packages, but I can only use `pip` for `2.7` installations of the packages but not for `3.5`. Any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

If we could see what pip printed before that, that might help narrow down what happened.

Without seeing how exactly the command failed (i.e. besides "with error code 1"), I'm going to guess you don't have BLAS and/or LAPACK installed. I'm sure this is a duplicate of some question already on here, since that's how I found out about it when I has this problem, but I can't seem to find it.

if you're on Ubuntu, you can download BLAS with

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

and LAPACK with

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

you might also need the packages `g++`, `gfortran` and `python3-dev`, also avaiable with `apt-get` on Ubuntu. I'm sure that packages also exist for whatever distro/OS you're using.

Comment: That worked thank you! And yeah you were right after looking up the error with the exact missing file names you mentioned, it was answered before but thank you for still answering it for me, I appreciate it!